# How to get world space coordinates in GLUT to check collision?

Tags: c++, opengl, collision, glut, bounding-box

I am making an OpenGL application based on GLUT, where there are some planets and a spaceship loaded from separate input files. Calculation of the bounding boxes are already implemented and I know how to check collision between the bounding boxes, *but I don't know how to get the word space coordinates from GLUT. As far as I know, I can only check collision, if the bounding box coordinates are in world space, but I have these in local.*

Here is bounding box calculator:

```
void calc_bounding_box(struct Model* model)
{
    int i;
    double x, y, z;
    double min_x, max_x, min_y, max_y, min_z, max_z;

    if (model->n_vertices == 0) { return;}

    min_x = model->vertices[0].x;
    max_x = model->vertices[0].x;
    min_y = model->vertices[0].y;
    max_y = model->vertices[0].y;
    min_z = model->vertices[0].z;
    max_z = model->vertices[0].z;

    for (i = 0; i < model->n_vertices; ++i) {
        x = model->vertices[i].x;
        y = model->vertices[i].y;
        z = model->vertices[i].z;
        if (x < min_x) {min_x = x;}
        else if (x > max_x) { max_x = x;}
        if (y < min_y) {min_y = y; }
        else if (y > max_y) { max_y = y;}
        if (z < min_z) { min_z = z;}
        else if (z > max_z) {max_z = z;}
    }

    // setting the coordinates of the bounding box for the specific model
    model->box.minX=min_x;
    model->box.minY=min_y;
    model->box.minZ=min_z;
    model->box.maxX=max_x;
    model->box.maxY=max_y;
    model->box.maxZ=max_z;
}
```

Here is the code, where I draw the model's bounding box coordinates:

```
void draw_bounding_box(const Model *model) {
   glLineWidth(1);
   glBegin(GL_LINES);
    glVertex3d(model->box.minX, model->box.minY, model->box.minZ);
    glVertex3d(model->box.maxX, model->box.maxY, model->box.maxZ);
   glEnd();
}
```

Before `glVertex3d(...)` there is `glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW); glLoadIdentity();`, so I suppose the coordinates translated into world space here and I need exactly these coordinates to check bounding box collosion, but I don't know how to get back these coordinates.

Anyway, I want to check collosion with this concept:

```
box1 = (x:(xmin1,xmax1),y:(ymin1,ymax1),z:(zmin1,zmax1))
box2 = (x:(xmin2,xmax2),y:(ymin2,ymax2),z:(zmin2,zmax2))
isOverlapping3D(box1,box2) = isOverlapping1D(box1.x, box2.x) and 
                             isOverlapping1D(box1.y, box2.y) and
                             isOverlapping1D(box1.z, box2.z)
```

In a GLEW project, I was checking collision in fragment shader and it was a clear situation, but I am not familiar with GLUT.

Comment: Use [`glGet`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glGet.xml) with `GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX`, `GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX` and `GL_VIEWPORT`. And use [`gluUnProject`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/gluUnProject.xml)

Comment: Yeah, that's a good idea! But as far as I know, "gluUnProject" is only for window coordinates specified by the mouse and I just want the coordinates of the bbox from the wordspace.

Comment: Then you have to do the matrix calculations yourself. Anyway, you have to retrieve the current matrices with [`glGet`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glGet.xml). Use a library for the matrix calculations (e.g. [OpenGL Mathematics (GLM)](https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.9/api/index.html))